# Spring JMS MessageListenerAdapter handleListenerException

Tags: spring, spring-jms

The default implementation of *onMessage* in *AbstractAdaptableMessageListener* does simply:

```
onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        onMessage(message, null);
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
        handleListenerException(ex);
    }
}
```

Even though the attempt at handling exception is commendable the actual handling in *handleListenerException* is not sufficient in most cases (it just logs an error level message about the exception).  Most real application who would love to make use of the *MessageListenerAdapter* and simply create a POJO to receive the formatted message have much more granular exception handling requirements.

Why was it done like this and could the *onMessage* implementation simply be replaced with a call to the *onMessage* method with a null Session argument and no try catch and simply allow the application to intercept (Java Enterprise interceptor or Spring Aspect) the *onMessage* JMS method and perform integrated/coherent exception handling?  In the past, I have had to subclass *MessageListenerAdapter* simply to override either the *onMessage* or *handleListenerException* method to handle exceptions myself.

Comment: as you mentioned `AbstractAdaptableMessageListener` is abstract, which implementation you use and how you use it ? with `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` ? if yes this method is not called and in case of exception `javax.jms.ExceptionListener.onException(JMSException)` will be called if you set an `ExceptionListener` of the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`

Comment: DefaultMessageListenerContainer is not a subclass of AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.  The only two subclass that extend it are MessageListenerAdapter (the one I referenced) and MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.  Not sure what you mean by implementation.  Not sure also how your comment addresses the question.

Comment: @HassenBennour In case it was not clear my question relates to how a client message consumer can handle all exceptions during processing and has nothing to do with how one can play in exception handling inside one particular container.  Most containers I use are Java EE servers.

Comment: sorry for the delay, i meant, which implementation of AbstractAdaptableMessageListener you use for the listener and how you use it ? by with DefaultMessageListenerContainer i meant that you need a container to connect to the broker and if you use this one or SimpleMessageListenerContainer ? if DefaultMessageListenerContainer the method you asking for is not called and in case of exception javax.jms.ExceptionListener.onException(JMSException) will be called if you set an ExceptionListener of the DefaultMessageListenerContainer